# Concatenate Worksheets in Google Spreadsheet to new worksheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I have a Google Spreadsheet that contains multiple worksheets. Most worksheets have the same columns but some have additional columns. I would like to concatenate all the worksheets into a single, newly created worksheet in the same workbook. Differences in columns should contain blank values.

Bonus points if it could be adapted for use on multiple workbooks. Also preferable if I could select the sheets to concatenate.

I have tried to write a script for this but I am struggling.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## The Mother of All Sheets

You could probably get all of the spreadsheets in your drive and do it for all of them as well.  But I'm not doing it.  This allows you to include the sheets that you want concatenated by adding them to the array includedSheet.

```
function concatAllSheets()
{
  var includedSheet=['Sheet1','Sheet2','Sheet3'];
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var allSheets=ss.getSheets();
  var sheetName='motherofallsheets-' + Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), Session.getScriptTimeZone(), "yyyyMMddHHmm")
  var mother=ss.insertSheet(sheetName);
  for(var i=0;i<allSheets.length;i++)
  {
    var sht=allSheets[i];
    if(includedSheet.indexOf(sht.getName())>-1)
    {
      var rng=sht.getDataRange();
      var rngA=rng.getValues();
      for(var j=0;j<rngA.length;j++)
      {
        var row=rngA[j];
        mother.appendRow(row);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm looking to improve this by creating a list of the worksheets in the workbook and clicking to select the worksheets I'd like to concatenate. Any ideas on this?

Comment: I'd probably use a sidebar that has a checkbox for each sheet and then a button that executes a function that combines all the checked sheets.